# How to place context.xml in war's META-INF?

Tags: gradle, war, meta-inf

I am building a webapp through Gradle's war plugin. In order to disable Tomcat's session persistence, I need to place the file `context.xml` in the `META-INF` directory of the war's root.

I attempted the following:

- Create the file `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` of the main project
- Create the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml` of the main project

However, when I build the project using `gradle clean war`, the produced war file contains a `META-INF` with only a `MANIFEST.MF` in it. It is as if my directory gets overridden.

How do I place `context.xml` in the war?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` is correct and works fine for me. Chances are that you went wrong somewhere, or that there is a problem with your build script.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. Thanks for confirming.